# What other uses than syntactical access for get and set on python classes, re. differing usages from decorators

Tags: python, dictionary, get, set

The toy example was made as a reminder of some of Python's special dunder methods, in this case, `__getitem__()`, and `__setitem__()` both of which can be invoked on extant dictionaries using syntax like the following:

```
k = 'key'
v = 1
d = dict()
d.__setitem__(k, v)
print(d.__getitem__(k))
```

My question is related to these dunder methods.
What other uses can they be put to in a class, and how do they differ from get and set decorators in terms of how and what they may act on?

How are the different 'newkey' objects and properties otherwise accessed from the class and its class instances from various 'levels' and between to the place on the class closest to where they reside?

```
class ADict():

    newkey = "!"

    def __init__(self):
        self.data = {}
        self.newkey = "?"

    def __getitem__(self, key): return self.data[key]
    def __setitem__(self, key, item): self.data[key] = item

d = ADict() # create an ADict instance, 'd'

d['newkey'] = 1.5 # create and set a new key on the class instance, 'd', dictionary
print(d['newkey'], ": bracket/key syntax accessed value of 'newkey' on class instance dictionary 'data'.")
print(d.newkey, ": dot syntax accessed value of 'newkey', the class instance variable 'newkey'.")
print(ADict.newkey, ": dot syntax accessed value of 'newkey' on class variable 'newkey'.")


d['oldkey'] = 'notnew'
print(d['oldkey'])
print(d.oldkey) # please debug
```

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking.

Comment: I guess you mean something else than "decorators".

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to cleverly push the boundaries to make a teachable example I can also learn from. My aim is getting clearer, I hope, and, yeah, I agree, decorators doesn't belong, so on the supposedly clear path I'd like to look at various access scenarios, between class variable containers, instance variable containers, and the same and variables between instances. It is known __setitem__(), and __getitem__() gift square bracket get and set syntax, so what gets better because of it?

Comment: Maybe there is confusion between `__getitem__`/`__setitem__` (used to change what square brackets do) and `__getattr__`/`__setattr__` (used to change what the dot does)?

Answer (score 0):

You could modify the `self.__dict__`:

```
class ADict():
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = {}
        for k, v in self.data.items():
            self.__dict__[k] = v

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.data[key]
    
    def __setitem__(self, key, item):
        self.data[key] = item
        self.__dict__[key] = item

d = ADict()

d['newkey'] = 1.5
print(d.newkey)
d['oldkey'] = 'notnew'
print(d.oldkey)
```

Output:

```
1.5
notnew
```